# delete warn on discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

im making a bot for my discord server but i have problem and my problem is this:
There is a command for the warning which is $warn and a command to remove the warnings is $clrw and another command to show the warnings is $warns but there is a problem.
When the user uses the $clrw command, it means that the variable that is accumulated during the warning becomes 0, but for all users, it means when the user use `$clrw @moonboy`Instead of only the desired person's warren being deleted, all people's warrens are deleted and this is a big problem!

my code:

```
@app.command()
# @commands.has_permissions(Warning = True)
async def warn(ctx,member: discord.Member,*,reason = None):
    global num
    if reason == None:
        await ctx.send(f"hey {ctx.author.mention} pls enter a reason!")
    else:
        num += 1 
        # await member.send(f"hey {ctx.author.mention} you have been warned bequase {reason} from {ctx.guild.name} pls dont do it again!")
        await ctx.send(f"{member} has been warned bequase {reason} ! ")
        return num
@app.command()
async def clrw(ctx,member:discord.Member):
    global num
    num = 0 
    await ctx.send(f"{member} warns has been deleted!")
@app.command()
async def warns(ctx,member: discord.Member):
    if num <= 0:
        await ctx.send(f"{member} has no warns!")
    else:
        await ctx.send(f"{member} has {num} warns!")
```

Answer (score 1):

the global variable `num` is not related to any particular user. If you wanted to do it per user, you could use a dictionary of their user ids.

```py
warns = dict()

# add a warning
userid = member.id # not sure if this is exactly how to get id, check docs
if userid not in warns:
  warns[userid] = 1
else:
  warns[userid] += 1

# clear warnings
warns[userid] = 0

# display warnings
if warns[userid] == 0:
  await ctx.send(f"{member} has no warnings")
else:
  await ctx.send(f"{member} has {warns[userid]} warnings")
```

(This is all pseudocode to show how dicts work. This will obviously not work when pasted directly into your code)

Comment: `if userid not in warns:
TypeError: argument of type 'Command' is not iterable`

Comment: @moonboy please read the last line. If you have something else called warns then change the variable name.

Answer (score 1):

You're lacking understanding of the variable `num`.

The Problem:
Atm what you are doing is, just adding and removing to the same variable or number in this case.
The code cannot know if u meant a diff user this way.

The Fix:
You should convert ur variable `num` to a dictionary. If the bot is gonna be for just one server then a simple dictionary should be enough.

Example:

- When doing the current `num +=1` replace it with `num[member.id] +=1`
- For reset instead of `num = 0` do `num[member.id] = 0`
- For the getting of warnings, instead of `num` do `num[member.id]`

In this case u will mention who exactly u want to reset the warns for, get it from or add to.

Also don't forget to convert the current `num` value where u set it the first time to `num = []`

Hope this helps!

PS. The amount of warns will reset on bot restart, as this is a variable in the code its not saved anywhere outside. I would recommend saving it in a file or redis server.

Example code for the error in the comment:
Use this for the command where u add the warning.
The reason u got that error is that u cannot add a +1 warning to an user who is not added in the array itself.

```
if member.id not in num:
   num[member.id] = 1
else:
   num[member.id] +=1
```

So u don't get a similar error with the getting of the warn.
Example:

```
if member.id not in the num or num[member.id] == 0:
   await ctx.send(f"{member} has no warns!")
else:
   await ctx.send(f"{member} has {num[member.id]} warns!")
```

Comment: tnx a lot but its have a error and
`list index out of range`

Comment: Apologies for the error there, i did not cover some important aspects. I have edited my solution posted.